# Jquery Why doesn't toggleClass work here?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this code:

```
$(".heading.media").click(function (event) {
    $("#cart").toggleClass("active");
    $('#cart').load('index.php?route=module/cart #cart > *');
});
```

But for some reason the `.toggleClass("active")` isn't working. It opens but I can't toggle after that.

When I remove `$('#cart').load('index.php?route=module/cart #cart > *');` it works just fine.

Why does `$('#cart').load('index.php?route=module/cart #cart > *');` cause trouble ?

Comment: create a fiddle for this

Comment: any error in console ??

Comment: Might be because `load()` inserts elements which duplicates the ID `#cart`

Comment: Try `toggling` after `load()`

Comment: @ShaunakD But the certain element #cart has had its class toggled before loading the external contents. I don't think it's a cause.

Comment: I read this line *It opens but I can't toggle after that* - I guess it means `#cart`  toggles first time. But not after loading - 2nd time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try selecting the element by [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) method and try.

```
$(document).on('click', '.heading.media', function (event) {
    $("#cart").toggleClass("active");
    $('#cart').load('index.php?route=module/cart #cart > *');
});
```

Comment: Ya, if `.heading.media` is child of `#cart`

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you very much it worked. May I ask why your code works and mine doesn't ?

Comment: @wamp Because you are removing children  from DOM using `load()` on its parent. Using delegation fixes it by binding `click` event on static parent. FYI, you could delegate event to `#cart` instead: `$('#cart').on('click', '.heading.media', handler);`  http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: @wamp, Because after toggling the classes there is a creation of new descendants, so with the use of this method it will attach event listeners for the new elements like the elements which has created on fly.